# qDebug not displaying anything

Tags: c++, qt, qt-creator, qdebug

Often when I need to debug something it's easier to print something using `qDebug()` instead of debugging step-by-step using a debugger. 
The problem is that from time to time the output of `qDebug()` isn't displayed at all! The same with `qWarning` and `qCritical`. What's strange, it only occurs when running the project normally (Ctrl+R), while when debugging (F5) the output shows up.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The solution is simple: 
add `CONFIG += console` to your .pro file and rebuild the whole project.

Answer (score 12):

Solution for me, As stated in https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1227295#c10  was :

1. look for `qtlogging.ini`  in `/etc/xdg/QtProject/` .
2. edit the current (or create the file `qtlogging.ini` if missing)

> ```
> [Rules]
> *.debug=false
> ```

to

> ```
> [Rules]
> *.debug=true
> qt.*.debug=false
> ```

3. recompile and check!

Comment: is working for me - seems that this entry is disabling the QDebug in recent systems like ubuntu 18.xx

Comment: im not sure if thats the cause, but i forgot to mention that i was on Ubuntu 17.10 and Qt 5.9

Comment: Also works if I put it in ~/.config/QtProject/qtlogging.ini

Answer (score 7):

I had the same problem and none of the answers here did help me. I found the solution here: https://lists.fedoraproject.org/archives/list/kde@lists.fedoraproject.org/thread/SB6QJZGVDLWWBZCMTNKMVZSSPPNREOYJ/

I had to set the environment variable `QT_ASSUME_STDERR_HAS_CONSOLE=1`. This can be done in code:

```
qputenv("QT_ASSUME_STDERR_HAS_CONSOLE", "1");
```

Or better in the "Kits" settings under "Environment".

Comment: Took me hours to get here. I used Qt to crosscompile for windows 10, but qDebug did not display anything. I was using cLion as the IDE as Qt environment does not fit me. Using the above in Qt Widget application fixed this.

Answer (score 5):

If you are running multiple instances of Qt Creator, qDebug does not work properly.

Answer (score 1):

My solution for this problem using

```
Windows 10 Education
Qt Creator (5.x)
Developing a Qt widget.
```

Problem:

So my issue was whenever I added a `QDebug` message it didn't show up in the application output although my code was 100% the same as in the tutorial and compiled fine.

Solution:

Right click on the file where you added the `QDebug` message, for me it was `main.cpp`. Click build. Press the green arrow on the bottom.

If this still doesn't work go to "Build"->"CleanAll", "Build"->"qMake" and go for the green arrow again.

Of course you have to `#include <QDebug>` and check that it is well spelled inside your code.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, it is somehow I forgot to click the 'Configure Project'. I am using QTCreator 4.11 and Qt5.14. When I create the project, I did not click on the 'Configure project' near the end of the creation process.

Answer (score 0):

Qt5.14.2, QtCreator 4.12.0:
What worked for me was to unselect Projects->Run->Run in Terminal...
Duh!

Answer (score 0):

You have to configure the logging rules. See [documentation](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qloggingcategory.html#logging-rules).

The format is:

```
    <category>[.<type>] = true|false
```

Logging rules are automatically loaded from the [Rules] section in a logging configuration file. These configuration files are looked up in the QtProject configuration directory, or explicitly set in a QT_LOGGING_CONF environment variable:

```
    [Rules]
    *.debug=false
    driver.usb.debug=true
```

Logging rules can also be specified in a QT_LOGGING_RULES environment variable; multiple rules can also be separated by semicolons:

```
    QT_LOGGING_RULES="*.debug=false;driver.usb.debug=true"
```

For example:

```
QT_LOGGING_RULES="*.debug=true;qt.*=false"
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved by adding:

```
export QT_ASSUME_STDERR_HAS_CONSOLE=1
```

to qtcreator start script placed in:

```
/home/yourUsername/qtcreator-10.0.0/bin/qtcreator.sh
```

provided by application downloaded from official site.

```
#! /bin/sh

export QT_ASSUME_STDERR_HAS_CONSOLE=1

# Use this script if you add paths to LD_LIBRARY_PATH
# that contain libraries that conflict with the
# libraries that Qt Creator depends on.

makeAbsolute() {
    case $1 in
        /*)
            # already absolute, return it
            echo "$1"
            ;;
        *)
            # relative, prepend $2 made absolute
            echo `makeAbsolute "$2" "$PWD"`/"$1" | sed 's,/\.$,,'
            ;;
    esac
}
..
//some lines...
..
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH
exec "$bindir/qtcreator" -user-library-path "$_ORIGINAL_LD_LIBRARY_PATH" ${1+"$@"}.
```

Update: Above solution is valid for Qt Creator. Using a terminal like xterm for starting, detached, a Qt application that use QProcess class for starting another Qt application (in my case in a project with more than one subprojects), readyReadStandardError() signal in the first one get correctly stderr of the second until terminal is closed when  communication between processes broken. I solved this second problem adding

```
     qputenv("QT_ASSUME_STDERR_HAS_CONSOLE", "1");
```

in main.cpp so:

```
    #include "frmparman.h"
    #include <QApplication>
    
    int main(int argc, char *argv[])
    {
        QApplication a(argc, argv);
        qputenv("QT_ASSUME_STDERR_HAS_CONSOLE", "1");
        a.setStyle("windows");
        frmParman w;
        w.show();
    
        return a.exec();
    }
```