# qDebug() doesn't print anything

Tags: c++, qt, clion, qdebug

I try to use Qt with CLion. My problem is that qDebug() doesn't print anything, but qInfo(), qWarning(), qCritical() and qFatal() works well. Here is my example code :

```
#include <QCoreApplication>
#include <QDebug>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);

    qDebug() << "This will not appear";
    qInfo() << "This will appear";
    qWarning() << "This will appear too";
    qCritical() << "This will appear too";

    return a.exec();
}
```

Specs :

- Qt : 5.5.1
- GCC : 5.3.1 (64bits)
- CMake : 3.3.2
- CLion : 1.2.2

Comment: Please try including `<QtDebug>` instead of `<QDebug>`, and try once again. Reference: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtglobal.html#qDebug

Comment: I've rebuild the whole project after including `<QtDebug>` instead of `<QDebug>` but it doesn't resolve the problem.

Comment: Which OS are you on?

Comment: I'm on Fedora 23 (4.2.6-301.fc23.x86_64). I've installed the same config on a Windows and it works. I think there is a problem with linux libraries. Maybe I haven't installed Qt properly on Fedora.

Comment: @Hello this is definitely useful/helpful thanks for posting. sry about other users downvoting. i gave an upvote. i ran into this issue when using `qtcreator`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [qDebug not displaying anything](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12799653/qdebug-not-displaying-anything)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Fixed by editing the ~/.config/QtProject/qtlogging.ini file as follows :

```
[Rules]
*.debug=true
```

[Related Bugzilla entry](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1227295)

Comment: altenatively, since this is kinda spammy: qml.debug=true worked for me

Comment: Unwanted ini files may also reside in other directories, like `etc/xdg/QtProject`

Comment: IF YOU DO NOT HAVE ~/.config/QtProject/qtlogging.ini, create it!
(helped =3)

Answer (score 0):

Try to enter `ctrl+shift+alt+/` ->`Registry` and tick the`run.processes.with.pty`.