# qDebug doesn't output anything

Tags: c++, qt

I have just start learning Qt using Qt Creator V4.13 and Qt V5.15.1, when I use qDebug(), qInfo(), qWarning() and qCritical() it doesn't show any thing in the application output.

**[EDIT]
I have checked 'run in terminal' and then clean and rebuild project, it now runs with "qtcreator_process_sub" with the required output of qDebug.**

.pro file

```
    QT       += core gui

greaterThan(QT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4): QT += widgets

CONFIG += c++11

# You can make your code fail to compile if it uses deprecated APIs.
# In order to do so, uncomment the following line.
#DEFINES += QT_DISABLE_DEPRECATED_BEFORE=0x060000    # disables all the APIs deprecated before Qt 6.0.0

SOURCES += \
    main.cpp \
    mainwindow.cpp

HEADERS += \
    mainwindow.h

FORMS += \
    mainwindow.ui

TRANSLATIONS += \
    ToDo_ar_EG.ts

# Default rules for deployment.
qnx: target.path = /tmp/$${TARGET}/bin
else: unix:!android: target.path = /opt/$${TARGET}/bin
!isEmpty(target.path): INSTALLS += target
```

MainWindow.h file

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QMainWindow>

QT_BEGIN_NAMESPACE
namespace Ui { class MainWindow; }
QT_END_NAMESPACE

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
Q_OBJECT

public:
MainWindow(QWidget *parent = nullptr);
~MainWindow();
private slots:
void addTask();

private:
Ui::MainWindow *ui;
};
#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

MainWindow.cpp file

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"
#include "QtWidgets/QPushButton"
#include "QDebug"
#include <iostream>

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent)
: QMainWindow(parent)
, ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
ui->setupUi(this);
connect(ui->addTaskButton, &QPushButton::clicked, this, &MainWindow::addTask);
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
delete ui;
}

void MainWindow::addTask()
{
qDebug()<<"Debug button";
qInfo()<<"Information output";
qWarning()<<"Warning output";
qCritical()<<"Critical output";
}
```

I have spent two days searching on Google but it all the answers were about undefine QT_NO_DEBUG_OUTPUT but it's defined.
what I have tried:
include "QtDebug" instead of "qDebug"
create qtlogging.ini with content:-

```
[Rules]
*.debug=true
```

Tried a clean build (clean and rebuild project) after each edit

specs:

Arch Linux (System is up to date I have just updated it)

V4.13 and Qt V5.15.1

CMake V3.18.2

Make V4.3

QMake V3.1

Comment: Does this answer your question? [qDebug() doesn't print anything](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34355549/qdebug-doesnt-print-anything)

Answer (score 1):

Just check in Qt Creator under Projects->Run->Run in Terminal if it is checked or unchecked. If it is checked, uncheck it and re-run the program.

Comment: It wasn't unchecked, anyway I have checked it and it qtcreator_process_sub appears, and the qDebug messages appear in it correctly, idk if this the expected behavior, when I unchecked it, it backs to not working.

Comment: you need a console to see the log. either you do as Sumit suggests or add a console to your app: `CONFIG      += console`

Answer (score 1):

To see lggoing output you need to:

1. Configure your project to have a console
2. Make sure qDebug() isn't disabled by defining QT_NO_DEBUG at build time
   (switch to a debug build).
3. Make sure logging isn't disable by system/usr configuration files.
4. If joining an existing project, check if a `qInstallMessageHandler()` has been called, in which caset he output may be being redirected somewhere.
5. If joining an existing project, make sure logging isn't suppressed by calls to `setSeverity` (not an issue in a fresh Qt Creator project).

**Step 1: To configure a console for you application, add**

```
CONFIG += console
```

to your .pro file, then rerun qmake and rebuild. Alternatively
enable "run with a console" in the run configuration gui provided by Qt Creator.

**Step 2: switch from a "release" to a "debug" build**

For this, you can use Qt Creator's gui on the lower left. This switches `CONFIG` from "release" to  "debug" in the .proj file. Which, among other things, tells qmake not to generate a makefile which calls the compiler with `-DQT_NO_DEBUG`. Since that would disable `qDebug`-level logging.
Alternatively, edit the .pro file yourself and rerun qmake, then recompile.

**Step 3: Check logging configuration files**

Since `qInfo()` doesn't work either on your system, this step probably isn't the problem in your particular case, but it generally can be an issue.

logging can be selectively enabled or disabled via rules set in a system and/or logging configruration file. Since 2015, `qDebug()` level has been disabled by default on major linux distros (ubuntu, fedora22+) via a system-wide `qtlogging.ini` which is included in  the distro's Qt5 packages.

on my system that means I have a `/usr/share/qt5/qtlogging.ini`:

```
$  cat /usr/share/qt5/qtlogging.ini
[Rules]
*.debug=false
```

To manually override this on the command line, you can set an environment
variable from the command line:

```
$ export QT_LOGGING_RULES='*.debug=true'

$ ./my_program
```

You can also edit the "build environment" in Qt Creator, if you ant to keep debug output disabled globally, but see it when running in Qt Creator.

I recommended you read [QLoggingCategory - Logging Rules](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qloggingcategory.html#logging-rules) for how this can be configured. See also [this](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1227295) fedora ticket about the change to disable by default.